# Trying to get property 'stock_name' of non-object error while inserting data

Tags: laravel

i am getting data using crawl and trying to insert into database. i get abbreviations of company name and have a command to get the full form of the abbreviations. it works fine if the company name already exists in companies table, and when the command handle is run new company name is also inserted and i can get the name from the table but cannot insert the name as it shows error. here is the code:

```
$data['symbol']=$es[1];
 $name=DB::table('companies')
          ->select('stock_name')
          ->where('stock_symbol',$data['symbol']=$es[1])
          ->first();

  if(!empty($name->stock_name)){

     $data['company_name']= $name->stock_name;
  }else{
     \Artisan::call("company:handle");

       $name=DB::table('companies')
                ->select('stock_name')
                ->where('stock_symbol',$data['symbol']=$es[1])
                ->first();    

        $data['company_name']= $name->stock_name;
  }
```

Comment: DB::table('companies')
          ->select('stock_name')
          ->where('stock_symbol',$data['symbol'])
          ->first();

==>"your query is wrong this is right query Try this"

Comment: still same error

Comment: Could you add your insert code statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve it by doing

```
//...
$data['company_name']= $name->stock_name ?? '';
//...
```

> [Null coalescing](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/7164/null-coalescing-operator-----) (??) is a new operator introduced in PHP 7. This
>   operator returns its first operand if it is set and not NULL.
>   Otherwise it will return its second operand.